# cannot migrate in laravel php framework

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

This error is shown in the terminal.

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: @DilipHirapara question has ubuntu tag, so yes

Comment: prolly the php-mysql package isn't installed, or for the wrong version

Comment: Yes I'am using ubuntu 20.04